# React useRef hook causing "Cannot read property '0' of undefined" error

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-hooks, react-native-maps

I'm trying to create a reference using the `useRef` hook for each items within an array of `data by doing the following:

```
const markerRef = useRef(data.posts.map(React.createRef))
```

Now, `data` is fetched externally through GraphQL and it takes time to arrive, therefore, during the mounting phase, `data` is `undefined`.  This causes the following error:

> TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined

I've tried the following with no success:

```
const markerRef = useRef(data && data.posts.map(React.createRef))
```

How do I set up so that I can map through the `data` without causing the error?

```
    useEffect(() => {
        handleSubmit(navigation.getParam('searchTerm', 'default value'))
    }, [])

    const [loadItems, { called, loading, error, data }] = useLazyQuery(GET_ITEMS)
    const markerRef = useRef(data && data.posts.map(React.createRef))

    const onRegionChangeComplete = newRegion => {
        setRegion(newRegion)
    }

    const handleSubmit = () => {
        loadItems({
            variables: {
                query: search
            }
        })
    }

    const handleShowCallout = index => {
       //handle logic
    }

    if (called && loading) {
        return (
            <View style={[styles.container, styles.horizontal]}>
                <ActivityIndicator size="large" color="#0000ff" />
            </View>
        )
    }   

    if (error) return <Text>Error...</Text> 

    return (
        <View style={styles.container}>
            <MapView 
                style={{ flex: 1 }} 
                region={region}
                onRegionChangeComplete={onRegionChangeComplete}
            >
                {data && data.posts.map((marker, index) => (

                        <Marker
                            ref={markerRef.current[index]}
                            key={marker.id}
                            coordinate={{latitude: marker.latitude, longitude: marker.longitude }}
                            // title={marker.title}
                            // description={JSON.stringify(marker.price)}
                        >
                            <Callout onPress={() => handleShowCallout(index)}>
                                <Text>{marker.title}</Text>
                                <Text>{JSON.stringify(marker.price)}</Text>
                            </Callout>
                        </Marker>

                ))}
            </MapView>
        </View>
    )
```

I'm using the `useLazyQuery` because I need to trigger it at different times.

Update:

I have modified the `useRef` to the following on the advise of @azundo:

```
const dataRef = useRef(data);
const markerRef = useRef([]);
if (data && data !== dataRef.current) {
    markerRef.current = data.posts.map(React.createRef);
    dataRef.current = data
}
```

When I console.log `markerRef.current`, I get the following result:
[image]

which is perfectly fine. However, when I attempt to map each `current` and invoke `showCallout()` to open all the callouts for each marker by doing the following:

```
markerRef.current.map(ref => ref.current && ref.current.showCallout())
```

nothing gets executed.

```
console.log(markerRef.current.map(ref => ref.current && ref.current.showCallout()))
```

This shows null for each array.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `useRef` expression is only executed once per component mount so you'll need to update the refs whenever `data` changes. At first I suggested `useEffect` but it runs too late so the refs are not created on first render. Using a second ref to check to see if `data` changes in order to regenerate the marker refs synchronously should work instead.

```
const dataRef = useRef(data);
const markerRef = useRef([]);
if (data && data !== dataRef.current) {
  markerRef.current = data.posts.map(React.createRef);
  dataRef.current = data;
}
```

Additional edit:

In order to fire the `showCallout` on all of the components on mount, the refs must populated first. This might be an appropriate time for `useLayoutEffect` so that it runs immediately after the markers are rendered and ref values (should?) be set.

```
useLayoutEffect(() => {
  if (data) {
    markerRef.current.map(ref => ref.current && ref.current.showCallout());
  }
}, [data]);
```

Comment: the `current` of each `markerRef.current` is null and I'm unable to access the properties, namely `showCallout`

Comment: Ah, I think understand the problem - the effect runs asynchronously so the refs are not created for the first render of the data. Really instead of an effect it should be a memoized function. Let me update with a solution.

Comment: thank you for this. The properties show up now, including `showCallout`, but when I tried to access it by `      markerRef.current.map(MapMarker => MapMarker.showCallout())`, it says `MapMarker.showCallout is not a function`

Comment: Each element of `markerRef.current` is itself a ref with a `current` property so I think it should be `markerRef.current.map(ref => ref.current && ref.current.showCallout());`

Comment: console.logging that code gives me `null`.  So does `console.log(markerRef.current.map(ref => ref.current && ref.current))`

Comment: When/where are you logging? The `current` properties will only be set on the refs subsequent renders if you're logging it the component function body. Does `const handleShowCallout = index => markerRef.current[index].current.showCallout();` not work when you trigger the `onPress`? With your previous comment about the properties showing up including `showCallout` I thought the refs were being populated correctly at some point.

Comment: The callout works fine when it's pressed even without the handler. What I'm trying to do is have all the callouts executed upon the component being mounted so that all the markers show the callouts at the same time. This is why I'm mapping the `markerRef.current` and invoking `showCallout()` in each ref. When I map `markerRef.current`, it shows all the properties within each array item no problem.  When tried to invoke `ref.current.showCallout()` in each array, it does nothing.

Comment: Alright, I think this is a case of the debugger being subtly misleading here. Your console.log(); works only because the debugger dynamically displays the the `current` value, not just the value at the time of console.log. Basically you need to wait until all of the refs are properly assigned before mapping over and calling `showCallout`. That could potentially be done in a useEffect - I'm not 100% sure if refs are guaranteed to be set immediately after first render. Let me add a suggestion.

Comment: unfortunately `console.log(markerRef.current.map(ref => ref.current && ref.current.showCallout()))` is still showing null. I've tried including the `            markerRef.current = data.posts.map(React.createRef);` and using `useMemo`, but to no avail

Answer (score 1):

Create refs using memoisation, like:

```
const markerRefs = useMemo(() => data && data.posts.map(d => React.createRef()), [data]);
```

Then render them like:

```
  {data &&
    data.posts.map((d, i) => (
      <Marker key={d} data={d} ref={markerRefs[i]}>
        <div>Callout</div>
      </Marker>
    ))}
```

And use the refs for calling imperative functions like:

```
  const showAllCallouts = () => {
    markerRefs.map(r => r.current.showCallout());
  };
```

See the working code with mocked `Marker`: https://codesandbox.io/s/muddy-bush-gfd82